# QTP - testing while browser/page title changes

Tags: automation, qtp

I am trying to make simple testing but failed because I have no clue how to handle with browser title that changes during the testing.

Simple example:
Google>Find "blabol"

Once its done, the browser title in QTP changes its name to "Google - results....". This is obviously problem when the search text is a variable that changes between iterations because the browser text is hardcoded.
I would need something like "this browser" and "this page", if you get what I mean.
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a couple of words, you can use a variety of properties for identification of the object in QTP, and you can use Regular Expressions to add even more flexibility.
For example, in your case, possible ways to address web browser would be the following.

1) Addressing first browser window (first opened) and any page

```
Set objBrowser = Browser("creationtime:=0")
Set objPage = objBrowser.Page("title:=.*")
```

2) If you assume that you always work with Google page.

```
Set objBrowser = Browser("title:=.*Google.*")
Set objGooglePage = objBrowser.Page("title:=.*Google.*")
```

3) Addressing page with particular search results

```
sSearchWord = "blabol"
boolRC = Browser("title:=" & sSearchWord & " - Google Search.*").Page("title:=" &  sSearchWord & " - Google Search.*")
```

Thank you,
Albert Gareev

http://automation-beyond.com/

Comment: Thank you for great answer. However I do not understand how it works if the object would not be in object repository (when using "*" e.g.)

Comment: @Tomas, you'll have to set the "regular expression" check box

Answer (score 1):

This is why QTP doesn't by default use the **title** as part of the description of the `Browser`. You should note that the description of the `Page` doesn't have to be strict since there is only one `Page` per `Browser` at any given time (different `Page`s only exist in order to help organize the object repository).

You may want to examine using the **"open title"** property in the description, since this doesn't change during navigation.