# Window Name changes by Date QTP

Tags: window, qtp

I need to build an automation script to test a windows-based application that changes its name every day.

Example : XXXXX LOGON - YYYYYYY Build 18.4.0.306 for 03/06 date.

XXXXX LOGON - YYYYYYY Build 18.4.0.307 for 03/07 date.

When I try to capture the window in Object Repository, it works fine until the next day when the window build name changes. I also tried providing text identifier, but it still wouldn't recognise.

How do I handle the Window Object title which changes dynamically each day?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do so by using regular expression in label. So your window object should be something like

`Window("regexpwndtitle:=XXXXX LOGON - YYYYYYY Build.*")`

.* is used to match any character zero or more times so in your case QTP will match property of the object starting from *XXXXX* and any/all characters after *Build*.
The same can achieved with descriptive as well as with object repository.

You may further read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2127283/qtp-testing-while-browser-page-title-changes)